# How to access data from objects nested in json array

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, javascriptserializer

I need to access data in nested json array of objects to be able to manipulate it further , using javascriptserializer in vb.net 4.0.

Here's the example string:

`json: {"multicast_id":216,"success":3,"failure":3,"canonical_ids":1,"results":[{"message_id":"1:0408"},{"errord":"Unavailable"}]}`

And here's the code I've written so far:

```
Class main
Public Property multicast_id As Integer
Public Property success As Integer
Public Property failure As Integer
Public Property canonical_ids As Integer
Public Property results As Results()
End Class

Class Results
Public Property message_id As String
Public Property errord As String
End Class


Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    Dim json As String
    json = txtInsert.Text

    Try
        Dim ser As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim exmp As main = New main
        exmp = ser.Deserialize(Of main)(json)

        Console.WriteLine(exmp.canonical_ids)
        Console.WriteLine(exmp.multicast_id)

        For Each item As Object In exmp.results
            For Each example As String In item
                Console.WriteLine("example")
            Next
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

I'm getting an error on the inner for each statement. If anyone could help me out with this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: ...and what is the error message?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the nested object correctly.

Instead your issue that once you get that nested object you are trying to use `For Each` to get each string property of that result. That is invalid.

For example, this doesn't work because `Results` does not implement IEnumerable so you can't use `For Each` on in:

```
Dim r as new Results();
r.message_id = "1:0408"
r.errord = "Unavailable"
For Each example As String In r ' <- this will throw an error
Next
```

Once you have a reference to the `Results` you then need to access it by property name:

```
For Each item As Results In exmp.results
    Console.WriteLine("message_id: {0}", item.message_id)
    Console.WriteLine("errord: {0}", item.errord)
Next
```

If you need to access the properties by name, then change Results to a different type.

For example, you can define results as an array of `Dictionary(of String, Object)` like this:

```
Class main
    Public Property multicast_id As Integer
    Public Property success As Integer
    Public Property failure As Integer
    Public Property canonical_ids As Integer
    Public Property results As Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
End Class
```

Then your can use:

```
For Each item As Object In exmp.results 'item will be a Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    For Each example As Object In item ' example will be a KeyValuePari(Of String, Object)
        Console.WriteLine(example.key)
        Console.WriteLine(example.value)
    Next
Next
```

Or by name like this:

```
    For Each item As Object In exmp.results 'item will be a Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        Console.WriteLine(item("message_id"))
        Console.WriteLine(item("errord"))
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that inner For Each.  You are already spinning through the array with the first loop.  You can be more specific with the type in the loop too:

```
    For Each item As Results In exmp.results
        Console.WriteLine(item.message_id & " : " & item.errord)
    Next
```